# Binding Perl hash keys

Tags: perl, hash

Is it possible to force different perl hash key to map to the same value? For example:

```
my %h = (
   aaa => 'val_1',
   bbb => 'val_2',
);
print "==============\n";
&dump();

$h{bbb} = \$h{aaa};    
&dump();

$h{aaa} = 'new';    
&dump();

sub dump{
    foreach my $k ( sort keys %h ){
    print "$k => $h{$k}\n";
    }
    print "==============\n";
}
```

This will print:

```
==============
aaa => val_1
bbb => val_2
==============
aaa => val_1
bbb => SCALAR(0x801d48)
==============
aaa => new
bbb => SCALAR(0x801d48)
```

But what I want would be:

```
==============
aaa => val_1
bbb => val_2
==============
aaa => val_1
bbb => val_1
==============
aaa => new
bbb => new
```

Comment: Question is, why would you want to do this. Most likely, you are trying to fix something that is better solved in another way. I.e. this is an [XY-problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377).

Answer (score 2):

You can store references to the values instead of values (as you show).  That's the "clean" way to do it.

The less clean way is to use a tied hash, as clintp suggests.

The very much less clean way is to alias:

```
use Data::Alias;
...
alias $h{bbb} = $h{aaa};
```

Note that this involves mucking about with perl's internals, which has some degree of risk should Data::Alias become unmaintained and newer perl versions break it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tie` to create a hash implementation that will do an automatic de-referencing when you retrieve the value.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!\usr\bin\perl 
use strict;
use warnings;

my %h = (
   aaa => 'val_1',
   bbb => 'val_2',
);
print "==============\n";
&dump();

$h{bbb} = $h{aaa};    
&dump();

$h{aaa} = 'new';    
$h{bbb} = $h{aaa};
&dump();

sub dump{
    foreach my $k ( sort keys %h ){
    print "$k => $h{$k}\n";
    }
    print "==============\n";
}
```

Output is:

```
==============
aaa => val_1
bbb => val_2
==============
aaa => val_1
bbb => val_1
==============
aaa => new
bbb => new
```

Comment: This doesn't quite do what I'm asking. `$h{bbb}` will be initialized to the right value, but I need it to update when `$h{aaa}` is changed.

Comment: @ajwood: I have edited my code. Now I got the output which you wanted.

Comment: Right, but I think you've missed the main point of my question. I'd like to bind the keys of the hash once, and then not need to know about the binding later; if one value changes *the other should automatically change as well*

Answer (score 0):

OR you can do this way which will give the output you wanted:

```
#!\usr\bin\perl 
use strict;
use warnings;
my %h = (aaa => 'val_1', bbb => 'val_2');
print "==============\n";
&dump();
my $ha = \$h{aaa}; 
$h{bbb} = $$ha;
&dump();
$$ha = 'new'; 
$h{bbb} = $$ha;   
&dump();
sub dump
{
 foreach my $k (sort keys %h)
 {
  print "$k => $h{$k}\n";
 }
 print "==============\n";
}
```